# Reduced model of society

Tags: logic

When astronomer, stars observer live in a city, they say: "Those artificial lights in the city, they confuse us, we are going out of this place, there the disturbing influences are fewer."

When a philospher wants to reflect about the beginnings of structures in society, he might also come to the conclusion, that the subject of his considerations would better be some reduced model of society, some might say it could be "a lonlely island with 200 people having survived a shipwreck".

What models philophers have used in the past (beside the lonely island) in order
to have a reduced view of society?

Thanks alot
Wolfgang